# What is the line mean? "this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName" in jQuery Hilghlight plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins, highlight

What is the use of the line

```
this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName
```

in following code from jQuery Highlight plugin.

http://johannburkard.de/blog/programming/javascript/highlight-javascript-text-higlighting-jquery-plugin.html

```
jQuery.fn.removeHighlight = function () {
  return this.find("span.highlight ").each(function () {
    this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;
    with(this.parentNode) {
      replaceChild(this.firstChild, this);
      normalize();
    }
  }).end();
};
```

Comment: Are you asking what the `.parentNode`, `.firstChild` and `.nodeName` properties do in a general sense (which I would've thought fairly self-explanatory), or what that line is doing in that particular piece of code (answer: nothing - the result of the expression is not used). I'm _pretty_ sure you're asking the latter, but...?

Comment: @nnnnnn then why the line is there? you can check the original code.

Comment: I don't know. It _could_ be because accessing one or more of those properties causes some side effect in some browser(s), or it could just be a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

`this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName` is not assigning its value to any variable. Basically it's a property not a function, so it won't make any effect. Looks pointless. It should find out parentNode of current node, then firstChild node of that parentNode and then get its nodeName. But in this case it's not getting used anywhere in the code snippet you provided

Comment: Speculation: it may have been used in debugging by the plugin author and never removed (e.g., used to be inside a `console.log` which was later removed, but the variable was left in, in case it was needed again later).

Comment: There is code in jQuery like this where a property is accessed but not assigned, but it's called for its side effect. [Source](http://docs.jquery.com/JQuery_Core_Style_Guidelines#JSLint).

Comment: hmmm...quite probable. But then he could have removed the entire line `console.log(this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName)` , instead of just removing `console.log(` and `)`  ... but it's harmless as of now :D

Comment: that's really interesting, what is IIRC though? Can you tell more about it?

Comment: @Shades88 If I Recall Correctly, but I looked it up and found the source (looks like I did mostly recall correctly) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName
```

This gets the tag's name (if it's an element, see [RobG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/257182/robg)'s comment) of the first sibling in reference to `this`.

Because it is not being assigned, it is weird. If it's being called for a side effect (perhaps to fix a browser bug), it's not clear (it should be commented).

That plugin's code is kind of weird.

Comment: It gets the [nodeName property](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-F68D095). If the node is an element, it will be the tagName, but if it's some other type of node, it will be something different. e.g. in some browsers it may be a text node, where the nodeName will be #text.

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I guess I should have made that distinction.

Comment: @alex do you still say the plugin code is weired its a fix only?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following eg:

```
<span class= "highlight">...</span>
<span class= "highlight">...</span>
<span class= "highlight">...</span>
<span class= "highlight">...</span>
....
```

Now there are multiple spans with the same class name. 
If you try to highlight ONE of these spans the jquery is fired.

Now which span to highlight is based on `this.parentNode.firstChild.nodeName;`
this refers to the span which has a request for highlight and the remaining is just internals inside the span.